# Atomically insert / update rows in multiple tables in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

My use case requires that tables A, B, and C need to have rows inserted / updated atomically. In other words, my application will break if A was updated, B was updated, and there was a catastrophic failure before C was updated.

So, either all three tables should be updated at once or not at all.

In SQLAlchemy I'm currently using the following function to execute my insertions.

```
self.db_conn.execute(table.insert(), dicts)
```

But from my understanding, this "execute" commits the transaction as well. So, if I were to `execute` row insertions on `A`, `B` and `C` in three different function calls, atomicity isn't guaranteed.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `self.dbconn` is a connection produced by `engine.connect()`, you can use it as a context manager, which commits when it exits:

```py
names = ['Alice', 'Bob', 'Carol']

with engine.connect() as conn:
    with conn.begin():
        for name in names:
            conn.execute(users.insert(), name=name)
```

The code snippet produces this output, showing each insert takes place within a single transaction:

```
2020-12-06 17:16:36,683 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine BEGIN (implicit)
2020-12-06 17:16:36,683 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine INSERT INTO users (name) VALUES (?)
2020-12-06 17:16:36,684 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [generated in 0.00019s] ('Alice',)
2020-12-06 17:16:36,684 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine INSERT INTO users (name) VALUES (?)
2020-12-06 17:16:36,684 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [cached since 0.0006672s ago] ('Bob',)
2020-12-06 17:16:36,684 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine INSERT INTO users (name) VALUES (?)
2020-12-06 17:16:36,684 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [cached since 0.0009919s ago] ('Carol',)
2020-12-06 17:16:36,684 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine COMMIT
```

See the docs [here](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/connections.html#using-transactions).

If we change the last element in the list to something that can't be saved - for example the built-in `int` function - the entire transaction is rolled back

```
2020-12-06 17:21:50,760 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine BEGIN (implicit)                                                         
2020-12-06 17:21:50,761 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine INSERT INTO users (name) VALUES (?)                                      
2020-12-06 17:21:50,761 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [generated in 0.00019s] ('Alice',)                                       
2020-12-06 17:21:50,761 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine INSERT INTO users (name) VALUES (?)                                      
2020-12-06 17:21:50,761 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [cached since 0.0006409s ago] ('Bob',)                                   
2020-12-06 17:21:50,761 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine INSERT INTO users (name) VALUES (?)                                      
2020-12-06 17:21:50,761 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [cached since 0.0009716s ago] (<class 'int'>,)                           
2020-12-06 17:21:50,762 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine ROLLBACK
```

Comment: Thank you! So my application has queries A, B, C, and D where (A, B, C) must be committed atomically but not necessarily D. I would like to use the same DB connection for all 4 queries instead of opening two different ones. Is that possible?

Comment: Yes.  Just do another `with self.db_conn.begin():` - the scope of the `begin` context manager is the transaction; it does not close the connection (given that `self.db_conn` is an instance attribute, you'll have to close it manually rather than using it as a context manager as I have in the answer).